# Text is printed in the wrong order in Python

Tags: python, text-formatting

I've written this program:

```
with open("Films.txt","r") as f:
    films=[]
    newFilms=[]
    for row in f:
        field=row.split(",")
        ID=field[0]
        title=field[1]
        year=field[2]
        rating=field[3]
        duration=int(field[4])
        genre=field[5].strip()
        newFilms.append(ID)
        newFilms.append(title)
        newFilms.append(year)
        newFilms.append(rating)
        newFilms.append(duration)
        print(newFilms)
        newFilms.append(newFilms)
        newFilms=[]
sortedbyLength = sorted(films,key=lambda x:x[4],reverse=True)
print("%-5s %-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s"%("ID","Title","Year","Rating","Length (mins)","Genre"))
for i in range(len(sortedbyLength)):
    print("%-5s %-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s %-20s"%(sortedbyLength[i][0],sortedbyLength[i][1],sortedbyLength[i][2],sortedbyLength[i][3],sortedbyLength[i][4],sortedbyLength[i][5]))
```

and the output says this:

```
['001', 'Ghostbusters', '2016', 'PG', 116]
['002', ' The Legend of Tarzan', '2016', 'PG', 109]
['003', 'Jason Bourne', '2016', 'PG', 123]
['004', 'The Nice Guys', '2016', 'R', 116]
['005', 'The Scret Life of Pets', '2016', 'G', 91]
['006', 'Star Treck Beyond', '2016', 'PG', 120]
ID    Title                Year                 Rating               Length (mins)        Genre
```

These print statements are in the wrong order, and not the order I expected them to be in.  Can anyone point me to where I went wrong here?
Thanks!

Comment: Tip: Let `pandas` do the work for you.  Read the file into a DataFrame.

Comment: What do you expect `newFilms` to be after `newFilms.append(newFilms) ; newFilms=[]`? Also, your file is CSV, you should use the `csv` module to read it.

Comment: What order do you want them to be? Did you possibly call `reverse` where you didnt want to?

Comment: No, they are in the correct order. Your last for loop is never run since `sortedbyLength` is empty since `films` is empty.

Comment: I think you meant `films.append(newFilms)` instead of `newFilms.append(newFilms)`

Comment: You also need to add the line `newFilms.append(genre)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your films list is empty, and the films on the output are from `print(newFilms)`. On the end of the loop you should do `films.append(newFilms)` instead of `newFilms.append(newFilms)`.

Comment: Thanks so much - It's working perfectly now!  Even just reading through it fresh this morning really helped!

Answer (score 0):

Your first mistake is you should write `films.append(newFilms)` instead of `newFilms.append(newFilms)`. Otherwise, `sortedbyLength` will be empty.

Also, there is a discrepancy in your provided output and the contents of the file. In your code, you are reading a field named `Genre` but the output doesn't include this. So, I would suggest you to check this as well.

Comment: Thanks so much!  It's working perfectly now - I must have been really tired when I was doing this last night!